# Are polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ solvable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, solvable-groups

I know that if $f$ is a polynomial over a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is solvable by radicals, then the Galois group of $f$ over $F$ is solvable. I've also seen many applications of this fact in demonstrating that certain quintic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ are not solvable by radicals. My question is this: does it follow that there exists a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$, or for that matter $\mathbb{C}$, that is not solvable by radicals? If this is the case, to prove it is it simply a matter of finding a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ whose Galois group is not solvable? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

$\textbf{Edit:}$

Given Steven Stadnicki's comment, I'll include precisely what I mean by "solvable by radicals". Here is the definition to which I refer in my question:

Let $f$ be a polynomial over a subfield $K$ of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\Sigma$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $K$. We say $f$ is solvable by radicals if there exists a subfield $M$ of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\Sigma$ such that $M:K$ is a radical extension.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'solvable by radicals'.  As the answers here have made clear, if you simply mean 'by taking roots of elements of $\mathbb{R}$', then certainly every polynomial is solvable, because _every_ member of $\mathbb{C}$ is the sum of a member of $\mathbb{R}$ and a square root of a member of $\mathbb{R}$ - but if you're looking for a formula in the _coefficients_ of the polynomial (similar to the quadratic formula, for instance), then such a formula can't exist for polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you for your comment. I've updated my question to include precisely what I mean by "solvable by radicals". I just have one more question. I thought that if a polynomial was solvable by radicals, as defined in my question, then one could find a formula for its roots in terms of its coefficients. However, the two interpretations of "soluble by radicals" to which you refer in your comment makes me second-guess that thought. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should second-guess that thought - essentially, Bruno's answer that $\mathbb{C}$ is a radical extension of $\mathbb{R}$ answers that interpretation of 'solvable by radicals' in the positive (the subfield $M$ is simply $\mathbb{C}$ itself), but that _doesn't_ imply any sort of explicit formula of the sort that you're looking for.

Comment: I think that makes sense. To check that I understand things properly, my current understanding is that if a polynomial over a field $K$ is not solvable by radicals, then there certainly is not a closed formula for its roots in terms of its coefficients. One the other hand, if it is solvable by radicals, then that does not guarantee that there exists such a formula for an arbitrary polynomial over $K$. Is that correct?

Comment: It would be more accurate, I think, to say that 'solvable by radicals over $\mathbb{R}$' means that we can solve the polynomial by taking roots (and combinations of roots, etc) of _arbitrary_ members of $\mathbb{R}$.  Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that _every_ member of $\mathbb{C}$ is of the form $a+\sqrt{-b}$ for $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$, this should be clear to see.  But that doesn't guarantee a formula in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help. However, that leads me to another question. Namely, how do you know when a formula for a polynomial's roots in terms of its coefficients can exist? In your first comment you said that no such formula can exist for polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$, and I'm curious why that is the case. As I'm new to this website, would it be more appropriate for me to post this as a brand new question than to continue this discussion in the comments?

Comment: It might be easier - and might well be worthwhile.  The short short version is that if such a thing existed, it would let you solve polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ using radicals.

Comment: Ah, of course. That makes sense. Thank you for your help. Because it seems relevant to the discussion in these comments, I'll mention that I just posted the question from my previous comment http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068726/when-does-a-formula-for-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ has order at most $2$. If a polynomial does not already split over $\mathbb{R}$, we adjoin a complex root and obtain $\mathbb{C}$, which is algebraically closed and hence is the splitting field of the polynomial. Thus every polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ is solvable by radicals.

Answer (score 7):

Every polynomial with real coefficients splits over $\mathbb C = \mathbb R[\sqrt{-1}]$. In particular, every polynomial with real coefficients is solvable by radicals (over $\mathbb R$).